# c# web service converted to node / express not working

Tags: c#, node.js

I have a working client writen in typescript and a legacy web server written in c# . I am attempting to convert the c# code into nodes.js / express.

The client fetch function:

```
export async function myFetch(url : String, data : Object | null)  {

    const bodyData = JSON.stringify(data);
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: bodyData
    }
    const fullUrl = serviceBase() + url;
    let res;

    try {
      if (data==null)
        res = await fetch(fullUrl);
      else
        res = await fetch(fullUrl, options);

      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error: ${res.status}`);
      }
      return await res.json();
    }

   catch (error : any) {
      AlertError('Web error',error)
    }
  
  }
```

and this is the interface (in C#) for one of the server endpoints:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/GetRidesForDate", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<Ride>))]
IEnumerable<Ride> GetRidesForDate(int date);
```

Using this, `GetRidesForDate` returns correct results.

In the node/express attempt I have:

```
const app = express ();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server Listening on PORT:", port);
  });
app.get("/GetRidesForDate/:date", (request: any, response: { json: (arg0: any[]) => void; }) =>
  {
    console.log('getRidesForDate '  + request.params.date);
    getRidesForDate(request,response);
  })
```

but if I call the client fetch with

```
rides.value = await myFetch("GetRidesForDate",18800);
```

the server code never arrives at `console.log`, instead I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '1', "#" is not valid JSON
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

The `1` here is the first digit of the fetch data. The client gives a 400 error (bad request).

If I use a browser and go to `http://localhost:3000/GetRidesForDate/18800` the node/express server responds correctly.

What should the parameters of `app.get()` be to make this work with my `fetch` command?

Comment: What does your payload look like, it is telling you that your JSON payload is not valid "Unexpected token '1', "#" is not valid JSON" and has nothing to do with c# to node conversion.

Comment: The payload (in both cases) is just a json-stringified integer. I forgot to add that the client returns a 'bad request'. Yes, maybe nothing to do with c# conversion, but the c# version accepts the same post without error which is why I have included it. Perhaps I should ask a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the fetch body `JSON.stringify(18800)` is not a valid JSON, and that parse error is coming from the server JSON body parser, hence the `400 Bad request` error (not familiar with c#, so no idea why there is no error there..).

So, you need to actually use a valid JSON:

instead of this:

```
const bodyData = JSON.stringify(data);//18800: not valid JSON
```

use this:

```
const bodyData = JSON.stringify({data}); //{"data":18800}: valid JSON
```

and then access it on the server via `req.body.data`.

Furthermore, it's unclear how you handle this request, because in your client fetch code, you seem to have two request: one GET, and one POST (which gives the error), but neither of them should work, because on the server you have only GET route which expects `:date` parameter, which you seem to send only via body in the POST request..

So, why not just always send it via body, and then if it's undefined, set it to something default, and do you processing.

And if you really want that route to work with both POST and GET, then you can use `app.use("/GetRidesForDate"....`, but there seems to be no purpose for that, and also, you'd need to add `:date` parameter in url, and not use `body` at all, which is why it's probably more convenient to always use `req.body`.

*Note: you can also remove extra `app.use(bodyParser.json());`, because you already use `app.use(express.json());`*

Try this:

client:

```
export async function myFetch(url : String, data : Object | null)  {

    const bodyData = JSON.stringify({data});
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: bodyData
    }
    const fullUrl = serviceBase() + url;
    let res;

    try {
        res = await fetch(fullUrl, options);

      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error: ${res.status}`);
      }
      return await res.json();
    }

   catch (error : any) {
      AlertError('Web error',error)
    }
  
  }
```

server:

```
// to make both GET and POST work, you could use `app.use("/GetRidesForDate"....`, but there seems to be no purpose for that..
  app.post("/GetRidesForDate", (request: any, response: { json: (arg0: any[]) => void; }) =>
  {
    console.log('getRidesForDate ', request.body.data);
    // if no req.body.data, add some defaults..
    getRidesForDate(request,response);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you. I have both GET and POST methods because the old C# code has a mixture of endpoint types. Adding the curly brackets to `{data}` fixed it for the node server, but broke it for the c# server! I am translating each API endpoint separately so now I have `const bodyData = nodeServer? JSON.stringify({data}) : JSON.stringify(data);` . Everything now working  - with a mixture of two servers until the translation is completed

Comment: great. that's strange.. see what kind of error it gives, is it the same, related to JSON serialization, or something else, or maybe something within the processing function.. because now the payload is changed, and correcting that might make it work..?

Comment: Error using the c# server with `{data}` is 400 (Bad request) - i.e. same error as the node server _without_ the curly brackets.

Comment: well, I'm not familiar with c#, but it seems it's something out there.. maybe it's expecting escaped string or something.. Try testing with some tools, for example, with curl: `curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"data":18800}' -X POST http://server/GetRidesForDate`